# How to get specific data out of a xml file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From commandline the following command works fine:

> echo 'cat
> //volume_trustees/*[contains(translate(.,"SMITH","smith"),"smith")]' | xmllint --shell /path/database.xml

But I want to put this into a shell script with search item as parameter.
But I don't know how to get this to work:

> y=$1
>
> up="$(echo $y | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')"
>
> lo="$(echo $y | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
>
> echo 'cat //volume_trustees/*[contains(translate(.,$up,$lo),$lo)]' | xmllint --shell /path/database.xml

This shows up the following error message:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: parameter error
XPath error : Stack usage errror
XPath error : Invalid operand
XPath error : Stack usage errror
XPath error : Invalid type
xmlXPathEval: 1 object left on the stack
//volume_trustees/*[contains(translate(.,$up,$lo),$lo)]: no such node
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Looks like you just need to change the outer single quotes (`echo '...'`) to double quotes (`echo "..."`) so that `$up` and `$lo` will be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes on the `echo` (should have it on the `y` assignment as well)

```
y="$1"

echo "cat //volume_trustees/*[contains(translate(.,$up,$lo),$lo)]" | xmllint --shell /path/database.xml
```

Wrapping the `echo` string in `single-quotes` prevented expansion of `$up,$lo and $lo`.

Comment: With the double quotes, the error is gone, but the result now gives me all entries instead of only those which are containing the content of $1

Comment: I needed to add the $up and $lo in single quotes additionally.

Comment: That looks like an xmlinit issue. Let me look at it, never used it before.

Comment: First time I'm using stackoverflow and I'm impressed how fast I get my question answered and commented *thumbsup*

Comment: Now all you have to do is select an answer if it was helpful to you. Just click on the number at the top-left of the question. Stackoverflow is an awesome site.